# Downsizing and rescaling an image using for loops

Tags: matlab

I'm relatively new to Matlab, and trying to understand why a piece of code isn't working.

I have a 512x512 image that needs to be downsized to 256, and then resized back up to 512. 
How I understand the mathematics, is that I would need to mean the pixels in the image to get the 256, and then sum them back to get the 512. Is that correct ? Following is the code that I'm looking at, and if someone can explain me whats wrong(its giving a blank white image), I would appreciate it:

```
w = double(imread('walkbridge.tif'));
%read the image

w = w(:,:,1);

for x = 1:256
    for y  = 1:256
        s256(x,y) = (w(2*x,2*y)+ w(2*x,(2*y)-1) + w((2*x)-1,2*y)+ w((2*x)-1,(2*y)-1))/4;
    end
end

for x = 1 : 256
    for y = 1 : 256
        for x1 = 0:1
            for y1 = 0:1
                R1((2*x)-x1,((2*y)-y1)) = s256(x,y);
            end
        end
    end
end

imshow(R1)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish by downsizing and resizing the image?  It is likely that this can be accomplished directly using imfilter (from the Image Processing toolbox) or, if you don't have access to that, can likely be vectorized, as mentioned by @Feilx below, which would be much faster and simpler

Answer (score 0):

I got your code to work, so you might have some bad values in your image data. Namely, if your image has values in range 0..127 or something similar, it will most likely show as all white. By default, [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) expects color channels to be in range 0..1.

You might also want to simplify your code a bit by indexing the original array instead of accessing individual elements. That way the code is even easy to change:

```
half_size = 256;

w = magic(2*half_size);
w = w / max(w(:));

figure()
imshow(w)

s = zeros(half_size);
for x = 1:half_size
    for y  = 1:half_size
        ix = w(2*x-1:2*x, 2*y-1:2*y);
        s(x,y) = sum(ix(:))/4;
    end
end

for x = 1:half_size
    for y = 1:half_size
        R1(2*x-1:2*x, 2*y-1:2*y) = s(x,y);
    end
end

figure()
imshow(R1)
```

I imagine the calculations could even be vectorised in some way instead of looping, but I didn't bother.